# Issue in vlookup comparison after getting rows and columns count of 2 different sheets. There is 1 mismatch in the results

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

In my vba script I'm getting the rows and columns count from 2 different sheets, and comparing those values against each sheets using Vlookup. Comparison Results are updating like  Not Found and Found. Whereas there is a mismatch in 1 result. Could anyone please help me on this?

```
 ExpectedDataRowCount = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

ExpectedDataColumnCount = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column

ExpectedSrc = "R2C2:R" & ExpectedDataRowCount & "C" & ExpectedDataColumnCount

ActualDataRowCount = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

ActualDataColumnCount = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column

Actualsrc = "R1C1:R" & ActualDataRowCountPlusone & "C" & ActualDataColumnCount

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP([Actual_Value.xls]Sheet2!" & Actualsrc & _
           ",[Expected_Value.xlsx]Sheet1!" & ExpectedSrc & _
           ",1,FALSE)),""Not Found"",""Found"")"
```

Comment: First row i ignoring i guess                                                                 Sl.No Values
1 Found
2 Found
3 Found
4 Found
5 Found
6 Not Found
7 Not Found
8 Not Found
9 Not Found

Comment: Could you also add some screenshot of the data you use? If you press insert an image you can directly upload it, no need to find an upload site first.

Comment: @Luuklag Actual Data Looks like this TR TEST
TR TEST
TR TEST
TR TEST
TR TEST
TR TEST
TR TEST + 1
TR TEST + 1
TR TEST + 1
TR TEST + 1

Comment: @Luuklag Expecetd Data looks like this 
TR TEST
NR TEST
SR TEST
JR TEST
AR TEST
ZR TEST
HR TEST
FR TEST
MR TEST
KR TEST
YR TEST
OR TEST

Comment: Please put that in a screenshot, it is horrible to see in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this case would benefit from using an IF statement instead of relying on excel formulas.

You should replace your:

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP([Actual_Value.xls]Sheet2!" & Actualsrc &_
 ",[Expected_Value.xlsx]Sheet1!" & ExpectedSrc & ",1,FALSE)),""Not Found"",""Found"")"
```

By:

```
For column = 1 to ActualDataColumnCount    
    For row = 1 to ActualDataRowCount
        For column1 = 1 to ExpectedDataColumnCountFor
             row1 = 1 to ExpectedDataRowCount

                IF Application.Workbooks("Actual_Value").Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(row,column)_
                = Application.Workbooks("Expected_Value").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row1,column1) Then
                   ActiveCell.Value = "Found"
                Else
                   ActiveCell.Value = "Not Found"
                End If
            next row1
        next column1
    next row
next column
```